# NServiceBus - Service Pulse - Can't connect to ServiceControl (http://localhost:33333/api/)

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I am using NServiceBus 5.  My messages are sending / receiving correctly, but I'm having trouble with Service Pulse.  I have configured the auditing using the default endpoint names.

When I navigate to Service Pulse (http://localhost:9090/) I get the following error.

`Can't connect to ServiceControl (http://localhost:33333/api/)`

Looking at my services I see that `Particular ServiceControl` is not started.  When I attempt to start it, it starts and immediately stops.

I have checked the logs at:

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Particular\ServiceControl\logs

and

> %WINDIR%\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Particular\ServiceControl\logs

But apart from the errors about the missing queues from yesterday (see below) - nothing.  When I attempt to restart the service now I get no errors.

**Anyone know what I should do to get Service Pulse working correctly?**

I deleted all my private queues yesterday thinking that they would be recreated automatically.  Now I realise only the endpoint ones are recreated, I have recreated some manually.

Right now along with my endpoint queues I have:

```
audit
auditqueue
error
error.log
particular.servicecontrol
particular.servicecontrol.errors
particular.servicecontrol.retries
particular.servicecontrol.timeouts
particular.servicecontrol.timeoutsdispatcher
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Ended up just uninstalling and reinstalling - fixed the problem.

`ServiceControl --uninstall`

`ServiceControl --install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and run `ServiceControl --install` in an admin Console and it will create the queues (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\ServiceControl> .\ServiceControl.exe --install`)

If not you need to add these queues manually or reinstall ServiceControl:
`particular.servicecontrol`
`particular.servicecontrol.errors`
`particular.servicecontrol.timeouts`
`particular.servicecontrol.timeoutsdispatcher`